# How to write a HID descriptor, REPORT_ID is confusing me

Tags: arduino, usb, hid

I am programming an Arduino to mimic an existing Sega 3 button control pad. My USB HID device will only send data if I include a REPORT_ID of 0x01 in my HID descriptor. If I leave it out the device is recognised as a HID device, but sends no data.

The device I am trying to mimic (SEGA's 3B Controller) generates a value of 0x01 as data[0] even if its HID Descriptor mentions no REPORT_ID.

Its HID descriptor (as reported by my USB device monitor) is this:

```
Item Tag (Value) Raw Data 
Usage Page (Generic Desktop) 05 01  
Usage (Joystick) 09 04  
Collection (Application) A1 01  
    Collection (Logical) A1 02  
        Report Size (8) 75 08  
        Report Count (5) 95 05  
        Logical Minimum (0) 15 00  
        Logical Maximum (255) 26 FF 00  
        Physical Minimum (0) 35 00  
        Physical Maximum (255) 46 FF 00  
        Usage (X) 09 30  
        Usage (X) 09 30  
        Usage (X) 09 30  
        Usage (X) 09 30  
        Usage (Y) 09 31  
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
        Report Size (4) 75 04  
        Report Count (1) 95 01  
        Logical Maximum (7) 25 07  
        Physical Maximum (315) 46 3B 01  
        Unit (Eng Rot: Degree) 65 14  
        Usage (Undefined) 09 00  
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,Null,Bit) 81 42  
        Unit (None) 65 00  
        Report Size (1) 75 01  
        Report Count (10) 95 0A  
        Logical Maximum (1) 25 01  
        Physical Maximum (1) 45 01  
        Usage Page (Button) 05 09  
        Usage Minimum (Button 1) 19 01  
        Usage Maximum (Button 10) 29 0A  
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
        Usage Page (Vendor-Defined 1) 06 00 FF  
        Report Size (1) 75 01  
        Report Count (10) 95 0A  
        Logical Maximum (1) 25 01  
        Physical Maximum (1) 45 01  
        Usage (Vendor-Defined 1) 09 01  
        Input (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,Bit) 81 02  
    End Collection C0  
    Collection (Logical) A1 02  
        Report Size (8) 75 08  
        Report Count (4) 95 04  
        Physical Maximum (255) 46 FF 00  
        Logical Maximum (255) 26 FF 00  
        Usage (Vendor-Defined 2) 09 02  
        Output (Data,Var,Abs,NWrp,Lin,Pref,NNul,NVol,Bit) 91 02  
    End Collection C0  
End Collection C0
```

Please note that there is no REPORT_ID in this descriptor. And the first report starts with 5 (five) 8-bit values.

The payload data produced by this gamepad looks like this:

0x01 0x7F 0x7F 0x7F 0x7F 0x0F 0x00 0x00

Please note the first value 0x01 here.

I have successfully reproduced the HID Descriptor as follows:

```
{
  0x05, 0x01,        /* Usage Page (Generic Desktop)  */
  0x09, 0x04,        /* Usage (Joystick)      */
  0xA1, 0x01,        /* Collection (Application)    */
    0xA1, 0x02,        /*   Collection (Logical)    */
      0x85, JOYSTICK_REPORT_ID,
    
      0x75, 0x08,        /*     Report Size (8)   */
      0x95, 0x04,        /*     Report Count (4)    */
      0x15, 0x00,         /*    Logical minimum (0) */
      0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  /*     Logical Maximum (255)   */
      0x35, 0x00,        /*     Physical Minimum (0)    */
      0x46, 0xFF, 0x00,  /*     Physical Maximum (255)  */
      0x09, 0x30,        /*     Usage (Direction-X)     */
      0x09, 0x30,        /*     Usage (Direction-X)     */      
      0x09, 0x30,        /*     Usage (Direction-X)     */      
      0x09, 0x31,        /*     Usage (Direction-Y)     */
      0x81, 0x02,        /*     Input (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)    */

      0x75, 0x04,        /*     Report Size (4)   */
      0x95, 0x01,        /*     Report Count (1)    */
      0x25, 0x07,        /*     Logical Maximum (7)   */
      0x46, 0x3B, 0x01,        /*     Physical Maximum (315)  */
      0x65, 0x14,        /*     Unit (20)   */          
      0x09, 0x00,         /*  Usage (undefined) */                              
      0x81, 0x42,          /* Input 66 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,Null State) */

      0x65, 0x00,         /* Unit 0 */
      0x75, 0x01,          /* Report Size (1) */
      0x95, 0x0A,          /* Report Count (10) */
      0x25, 0x01,         /* Logical Maximum (1) */
      0x45, 0x01,         /* Physical Maximum (1) */
      0x05, 0x09,         /* Usage Page Buttons (9) */
      0x19, 0x01,          /* usage minimum 1 */
      0x29, 0x0A,          /* usage maximum 10 */
      0x81, 0x02,           /* Input 2 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position) */
       
      0x06, 0x00, 0xFF,          /* usage page (vendor specific) */
      0x75, 0x01,        /*     Report Size (1)   */
      0x95, 0x0A,        /*     Report Count (10)    */
      0x25, 0x01,        /*     Logical Maximum (1)   */
      0x45, 0x01,       /*     Physical Maximum (1)  */
      0x09, 0x01,        /* Usage (undefined) */
      0x81, 0x02,         /* Input 2 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position) */
    0xC0,

    0xA1, 0x02,        /*   Collection (Logical)    */
      0x75, 0x08,       /* report size (8) */
      0x95, 0x04,       /* report count (4) */
      0x46, 0xFF, 0x00,  /* Physical maximum (255) */
      0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  /* Logical maximum (255) */
      0x09, 0x02,         /* Usage 2 (mouse) */
      0x91, 0x02,         /* Output 2 (Data,Variable,Absolute,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non Volatile) */
    0xC0,      
  0xC0               /* End Collection      */
};
```

And my payload data looks like this:

```
  m[0] = 0x7f;
  m[1] = 0x7f;
  m[2] = _x_axis;
  m[3] = _y_axis;
  m[4] = _buttons;
  m[5] = _start_button;
  m[6] = 0x00;
```

Any attempt of mine to remove the REPORT_ID from my descriptor results in no data being sent. I have tried removing the REPORT_ID, changing the first report to 5 bytes and adding a 0x01 in my payload but it results in no data being sent.

How do I produce payload data starting with 0x01 without a REPORT_ID included in the HID descriptor?